# Deleting user posts, restrict delete to author of post

Tags: php

So right now, I've got a working PHP script that can delete posts from my network. But right now, everyone is able to delete everyones posts if they are logged in. I want restrict this to the authors of the posts, so they are only able to delete their own posts. How can I do this?

This is how my **delete.php** it looks like:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; 

include "connect.php"; 

if(isset($_GET['id'], $user_id)) 
{ 

mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=".$_GET['id']); 
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "UPDATE users SET posts = posts - 1 WHERE id='$user_id' "); 
header("location: index.php"); 
} 
mysqli_connect();
?>
```

In the main page where the posts are being displayed, the button is displayed like this:

```
<a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $postid . "\"> Delete </a>
```

It finds the postid itself. I have two tables, users and posts. Both has the column user_id, so the post table does get same user_id as in users_id.

Comment: First close that SQL injection. Use parameterized queries. Add `and authorid = ?`  to your query and pass `$_SESSION['user_id']` to it, or however you associated the owner of a post.

Comment: First you need to check if the user logged in only is able to edit or delete.So first use a query to check for the user in your post table .

Comment: so check if the person clicking is allowed to do whatever the click represents. that's not a database issues. that's up to YOUR code to enforce.

Comment: I closed the MySQL connection, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code is not safe!

Keep in mind that everyone can mess with your system when not escaping user input! You should read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

As you are checking already by the session if the deleting user is logged in, you now have to fetch the data from the deleting post (look for the post with the given post id in $_GET['id'] (*ESCAPE IT!!!*)) in table "posts". As you said, your table "posts" contains the field "user_id" and if you get this value you can simply compare it by the id given by $_SESSION["user_id"]